# What is the difference between print('text' +str(variable)) and print('stuff', variable) in python?

Tags: python

When writing print statements in python is it better practice to write

```
print('some text', variable, variable, expression)
```

or

```
print('some text' + str(variable) ...)
```

How is print handling these differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main difference is if you were to "parameterize" the print function (as Vikram so eloquently said), `print` has a default `sep` parameter that separates your parameters with whatever `sep` may be (defaulted to a `' '`). without splitting your variables into parameters and just concatenating them into one string, there will be no spaces.
ie:

```
>>> print(1,2)
1 2
>>> print(str(1)+str(2))
12
```

I think another thing you are wondering is the calling of `str`. Simply put, print calls `str(parameter)` on your parameters regardless so, in that respect, there really is no difference.

In conclusion, the string that is outputted by `print` acts almost identical to:

```
sep.join(parameters) #where sep is defaulted to ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Python, but as a basic difference would be related to the performance.

`print('some text', variable, variable, expression)` - This is called Parameterized which improves performance.

`print('some text' + str(variable) ...)` - incurs the cost of constructing the message parameter, i.e. converting the type to a String

Comment: The former also separates the items by default using `sep` (which is a space by default).

Answer (score 1):

In general,

```
print('some text', variable, variable, expression)
```

will be more efficient than

```
print('some text' + str(variable) ...)
```

which constructs a new string object, displays it, then immediately discards it. Unless the list of arguments is long and resulting string is huge, though, I doubt you'll ever notice the time difference. I think it's more important that the first is more idiomatic than the second.